# Putting a JLabel on top of a JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jlabel

I would like to know how to put a JLabel on top of another JLabel at a specific position, in a class that extends JPanel in Java. People have asked for help with this before but the solutions that I found do not satisfy me. I am using GridLayout, here is some of my code:

```
//imports

public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    Icon background = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/background.jpg"));
    Icon foreground = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/foreground.jpg"));
    JLabel backgr = new JLabel(background);
    JLabel foregr = new JLabel(foreground);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");

public Game() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        backgr.addMouseListener(this);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addMouseListener(this);
        backgr.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(backgr);
        backgr.add(foreground);
    }
}
```

(I have a lot of other methods in this class, such as some mouse stuff, but I don't include them here since they are not relevant to this problem.)

Currently the code almost works as I want, the foreground picture is displayed on top of the background, right in the middle of it. But I would like the foreground picture to be displayed at specific coordinates on the background picture. I thought that if I wanted to display the foreground at coordinates (50, 50), I could say backgr.add(foreground, 50,50), this compiles but returns an error when I run the program. Any tips of what to do? It would be really appreciated.

**Edit:** I discovered that by saying backgr.setLayout(null), backgr.add(foregr) and then foregr.setLocation(50,50), we can do what I was looking for. But since not using a layout manager is discouraged, I am looking for better solutions, so that I can use the coordinates on the backgr Icon.

Comment: what error does it return?

Comment: @Prasad "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position." No matter which coordinates I pick I get this, I assume this is the wrong way to go

Comment: Read the API, this method is NOT used to specify X/Y coordinates.

Comment: @camickr You are right. What method is used then?

Comment: *"Putting a JLabel on top of a JLabel"*  Something I forgot to mention on the other answer, there are times when it simpler to just go directly to custom painting, even if rendering components.  E.G. in this case, you might render both labels to separate images, then knowing the width and height of them, render both to a 'canvas' for showing the user.  The canvas might be a custom painted `JPanel` (like I did with the gradient paint) or it might be yet another image, displayed in a `JLabel`.  I prefer the 2nd approach for anything that is not resizable. It is simpler, does not need to ...

Comment: ... extend anything, we can still layout the (label containing the) image without worrying about `@Overriding` the preferred size of a component (which has its own subtle complications).  For your future questions, if I ask you 'how will it be used?', the more detail you can give me, the better I can determine which is the best approach to use.  But without that detail, I risk coming up with 'the right answer to the wrong question'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> People have asked for help with this before but the solutions that I found do not satisfy with me since they require me to set the frame layout to null, but I am using GridBagLayout

The frame is using a GridBagLayout.

You are adding the foreground JLabel, so the background JLabel. The background label can use any layout (including null) that you wish.

> the foreground picture is displayed on top of the background, right in the middle of it.

That is because you are using a BorderLayout and are adding the foreground to the CENTER, which is the default when you don't specify a constraint.

Comment: So I say backgr.setLayout(null) first? Then if I want to display the foreground picture on coordinates (50,50), do I say backgr.add(foreground, 50,50) afterwards? I just tried this and I still get an error, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Sid, I thought you said you found postings that show you how to use a null layout?

Comment: Yes I said that, I realized that I was unclear. Those postings show how to display a JLabel on top of another JLabel, but not how to do it on specific coordinates. I can rephrase my post. But do you know how to do this?

Comment: The usage of a "null layout" is strongly discouraged, but if you really want to know how then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Absolute Positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) for more information and a working example.

Comment: If it is discouraged, then I would rather find a different way. So if you know of a different and a better way to solve the problem by using a layout manager, please tell me! By the way, thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know your full requirement, but my general rule is that a null layout should only be used when you have random/dynamic positioning of components that change either by movement in a game or by a user dragging a component around the screen. In other cases you can use layout managers to position static components. You can do things like add an `EmptyBorder` around the label of size (50, 50) to make it appear bigger, then you use a layout manager that would position the label at the top/left of the panel.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking for a dynamic positioning of the components (the foreground should move in the future), so perhaps null layout is the right thing. But I only want the foreground to be on top of the background JLabel, so I want the coordinates to be relative to the background (so that when I say foregr.setLocation(1,1), I mean (1,1) on the background but not on the whole frame). This means that even if the window is resized, the program still works right. If you know how to do this, then I am all set. If it is hard or not possible, I suppose coordinates relative to the frame are OK.

Comment: You are adding the foreground label to the background label, so the setLocation(...) values are relative to the background.

Comment: Alright problem solved. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42695/discussion-between-sid-and-camickr)